# What is the difference between the four attribute values between full, fast, fast-unsafe,warp for --sync?

Tags: polkadot, sync

polkadot network sync mode: `--sync`

Blockchain syncing mode. [default: full] [possible values: **full, fast, fast-unsafe,warp**]

1. What is the difference between these four attribute values?
2. What is the difference between their synchronization speed?

Comment: please check https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/334/what-kinds-of-sync-mechanisms-does-substrate-implement/406